# Passing const char to incompatible type double

Tags: c++, ios, c, libxl

Whenever i define this string as a number, it gives me the error ***'Passing const char to incompatible type double'***. When i define the string as xlSheetWriteStr there are no issues but when i define it as a number it gives me the error.

Here is the code with the issue -

```
 xlSheetWriteNum(sheet, 2, 1,[self.personcityTextField.text UTF8String], 0);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is xlSheetWriteNum defined?

Comment: something is wrong with `[self.personcityTextField.text UTF8String]`

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/aDy3Q56.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fourth parameter to `xlSheetWriteNum` expects a double and not a string value. Try this:

```
xlSheetWriteNum(sheet, 2, 1, [self.personcityTextField.text doubleValue], 0);
```